# how do I make x11/xQuartz stop opening up

Tags: vim, zsh, tmux, iterm, prezto

the past week or so, I've been having an issue where whenever I open iterm (and sometimes when I just open vim) xquartz/x11 will open. I have version 7.4.1941 of vim. How do I make it stop opening xquartz?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, each time I started vim, XQuartz would boot up.

## The problem is `clientserver`

I recently reinstalled vim with `clientserver`, and it seems that that requires XQuartz.

If you install like this, XQuartz will start when vim is run:

```
brew install vim --with-client-server
```

You can check this with `vim --version | grep clientserver`. If there is a `+` before `clientserver`, it is installed, and the opposite if there is a `-` .

## Solution: Remove `clientserver`

(unless you really need it)

Simply uninstall and install the default version.

```
# Given that it was installed with brew
brew uninstall vim 
brew install vim
```